# Day and Time fields using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby and Rails . I have a requirement in which I have to store just the day of the week and time in the database.

Can I get the gudiance on how to implement the above requirement.

Comment: Are you trying to save the day of week + time to mark a reoccurring event?  Or are you trying to save a date, but only care about the day of week and time?

Comment: I am trying to save the week day + time for recurring event. Can you suggest any library for that purpose.

Comment: If that's the case, I would avoid the solution proposed by Flexoid.  Saving a full DateTime would be misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absent more usage details, I'd keep it simple.

- Store the day of the week as an integer where `0 = Sunday`.
- Store the time as a string where `"13:45" = 1:45pm`.